# Is it necessary to override onSaveInstanceState to save private fields?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, activity-lifecycle

I have a simple Activity class with an `onCreate()` method that sets a private boolean field if all initialisation tasks succeed. I read the value of this boolean in other parts of the class.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private boolean initializationSucceeded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        //if everything succeeded...
        initializationSucceeded = true;
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to override `onSaveInstanceState()` to save the state of this boolean, or is what I have fine? I'm afraid I don't quite know what happens to private field members during all of these activity lifecycle edge cases, so hopefully someone can explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to save it, because everytime onCreate is called and completed initialisationsucceeded will be true. OnCreate is the first thing called after lifecycle events like rotations. Unless you have a thread that is started in onCreate that requires the truth value of initialasationsucceeded then you should be fine.

Comment: Yes. Just to expand on this answer (since I understand the activity lifecycle a lot better now), you only need to save the state of members that have the potential to get changed after `onCreate()` e.g. a private field that can be modified via a public getter. If your member is always set to the same value in `onCreate()` and can never get modified thereafter, there is no need to save its state, because it won't ever have a "dynamic" value.

Comment: Pretty much yes. You really only need to save the state of variables that are being manipulated, especially ones by the user.